# Help me find old study of huge space shuttle with 1,000 ton payload

Tags: space-shuttle, shuttle-derived

In the late 1970s/early 1980s I read a study about up-sizing the space shuttle to carry 1,000 tons(!) payload to earth orbit. There was a crude drawing of such a beast, and if I remember correctly, the whole craft at launch weighed 27,000 tons! I believe it was two stages, both reusable, but both were piloted (IIRC), and liquid rocket propelled. No solid fuel boosters.

Edit:It was an article in a magazine, as I remember.

I tried googling the study, but no luck; my google-fu is weak, I guess. Can anyone help me find the study on-line, please?

Edit2: The first stage was *not* piloted and so couldn't be reusable, like the S-IC.. There was also a drawing of a smaller version with a smaller (100 ton?) payload.

Comment: Sea Dragon?  The Chrysler SERV?

Comment: It was a stacked staged rocket launched from a land base, like Cape Kennedy.

Comment: An article in a magazine doesn't necessarily mean there was a serious study done. Can you remember what magazine it was?

Comment: Sorry, can't remember the mag. Perhaps it was a space/aviation specialty issue. True, it was not necessarily a very serious study. However, they did compute things like total weight and size and had a drawing of what it would look like. Also (again, looking back 40+ years ago), they had a drawing of a smaller, 100(?)  ton capacity vehicle along the same outlines..

Comment: Possibilities with enough payload: Rockwell Star-Raker, ROMBUS, Nuclear Liberty Ship (nuclear lightbulbs, yeah!), GCNR NEXUS (please don't), the various Orion vehicles, a deeply insane concept with 20,000+ (sic) tons of cargo called Aldebaran.

Comment: I loved Star Raker. No booster though.

Comment: ikrase: how many of those have 1,000 ton payload to LEO? No boosters? Circa 1975?

Comment: As I recalled from 40y ago the vehicle was a jumbo-ized STS system. The 1st stage was liquid fueled rocket-propelled with [F-1s](http://www.astronautix.com/f/f-1.html), and the second a giant Columbia with a proportionate fuel tank. Using the cube root law, it was therefore 3.7 times bigger.

Comment: You might be interested in this video: [KSP - Delivering 1000 tons of payload to orbit with a 600 ton SSTO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhmlWdlpX2o)

Comment: Kerbils! Very interesting, thanks Fred.

Comment: I've created a for-all-mankind tag intended for discussion of science & technology aspects of the show. 
It would be worth adding this tag to your question to aid searching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only serious launcher proposal I've ever heard of at that scale was [Sea Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Dragon_(rocket)).

Sea Dragon doesn't quite fit your recollection, though. It's a 500-ton to LEO design, not 1000 tons, with a liftoff weight of about 20,000 tons. It wasn't derived from the shuttle in any way (although a big cheap booster with a pressure-fed engine was contemplated as a first stage for the shuttle); recoverability was optional and parachute based rather than soft landing, and it was uncrewed.

[The proposal was fairly thorough](http://neverworld.net/truax/Sea_Dragon_Concept_Volume_1.pdf), but it was still just a paper design.

The alternate-history TV series *For All Mankind* shows a Sea Dragon launch in a scene at the end of the first season finale.

Skimming the Aerospace Project Review blog, which digs up a lot of old proposals, the only other thing in that class I've found is the Boeing [Large Multipurpose Launch Vehicle](http://www.aerospaceprojectsreview.com/blog/?p=3774) (1968 concept, 500-1500 tons to LEO, not very shuttle-y).

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen Sea Dragon before. The concept I read about was definitely 1000 ton payload, and the drawing looked like the orbiter on steroids atop a huge winged first stage. Must have had nineteen or twenty F-1s!

Comment: That LMLV was really heroic!  Larger than the one above, even. I'm sure that one had no solid fuel rockets however. But it has been 40+ years since I read it for sure.